# UITableView error: indexpath.row is starting from 1 instead of 0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

indexpath.row is starting from 1 instead of 0.

How can I get rid of the empty index 0?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

var path: String?
var data: String?
var TableView1 = [String]()
var TableView2 = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("textFile", ofType: "txt")
    self.data = String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    if var content = (data){
        //var line: [String] = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        var chp: [String] = content.componentsSeparatedByString("#")

        TableView1 += chp
        TableView2 += sec
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return TableView1.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    Cell.textLabel?.text = TableView1[indexPath.row]

    return Cell
}
}
```

Here is a screen shot of what the text file reads and how it is displayed on the tableview

[image]

[image]

Comment: @dip heres the other question

Comment: how are you accessing from table view ? I mean the array here seems fine ! there may be some issue in your access mechanism !

Comment: Hey dip. I edited in the whole code. nothing seems to be wrong. but it still prints an empty cell before initiating the text from the text file

Comment: please share your ***cell for row at index path method*** of table view !

Comment: @dip its there. see the code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is normal, from the documentation of `componentsSeparatedByString` In the `NSString` class:

> **Discussion.**
>   The substrings in the array appear in the order they did in the receiver. Adjacent occurrences of the separator string produce empty strings in the result. **Similarly, if the string begins or ends with the separator, the first or last substring, respectively, is empty.** For example, this code fragment:
>
> `NSString *list = @"Karin, Carrie, David";
>   NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];`.
>   produces an array { @"Karin", @"Carrie", @"David"" }.
>
> **If `list` begins with a comma and space—for example, @", Norman, Stanley, Fletcher"—the array has these contents: { @"", @"Norman", @"Stanley", @"Fletcher" }**
>
> If `list` has no separators—for example, "Karin"—the array contains the string itself, in this case { @"Karin" }.

Your text file begins with the separator character, therefore an empty string is the first item of the array.

---

Edit:

A solution is just to remove the first item:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

  var tableData = [String]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("textFile", ofType: "txt"),
      data = String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {
        tableData = data.componentsSeparatedByString("#")
        tableData.removeAtIndex(0)
    }
  }
}
...
```

Comment: what if its "#" there is no space? or a ',' for it to assume its a sting?

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: sorry. i just read that last bit all works fine now. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

***Update*** here, i have only changed one line and other are same as your code
i noticed that your source file may contains blank line at very top, that is causing first cell empty !

```
//  tab.swift
//  TestGround
//
//  Created by dip on 9/3/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 apple. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class tab: UITableViewController {

    var path: String?
    var data: String?
    var TableView1:[String] = [] //Changed this line
    var TableView2 = [String]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("dip", ofType: "txt")
        self.data = String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        if var content = (data){
            //var line: [String] = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
            var chp: [String] = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")

            TableView1 += chp
            TableView1 += chp
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        println("count is \(self.TableView1.count)")
        return TableView1.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cel", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell //little change but will not effect

            var text = TableView1[indexPath.row] as String //just created a variable of string
            println(text)

        Cell.textLabel?.text = text // added text to label



        return Cell
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for that, but still the same. and no theres no space in the text file.

Comment: please share your screen shot of simulator! and your text file ! i ma sure about  that blank line is the cause of empty cell on table view !

Comment: see pics of the text file and tableview above

Comment: try to remove and add that text file again ! it is actually adding first line as empty string and which is obviously being set on cell of table view !